# Ltree find parent with most children postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find the parent with the most children. I feel like this should not be so hard however I find myself struggling.

I am using postgresql and Ltree.

Thank you

Comment: Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601829/postgresql-ltree-query-to-find-parent-with-most-children-excluding-root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same logic as for any other case, find a function that will give you the parent and group by it. This should work:

```
SELECT subpath(path,0,1), count(*) 
FROM test
GROUP BY subpath(path,0,1)
ORDER BY count(*) DESC limit 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8fb17/5

Comment: Thank you for your response. I get a PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid positions

Comment: @Davinj The example fiddle works, I can't really say why you're getting the error without seeing your query and schema.

Comment: @Davinj Oh, I see what causes the error, you'll need a condition in WHERE clause to limit the select only to those ltrees that have enough levels. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8fb17/15

Comment: Gotcha! yes when I got rid of the "" (empty) paths it worked great. I appreciate your quick response. Thank you!

Comment: In my tree structure I have a parent that has 6 children and this query is giving me a node that has 1 child instead of the parent that has 6

Comment: @Davinj It should work, I can't really say what's wrong without seeing the query and example of the behaviour. Maybe you ommited the DESC in order by? Remove the limit and see if the count is correct.

Comment: @JakubKania: Should have been `subpath(path, -1, 1)`. [More details in the answer to his follow-up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601829/postgresql-ltree-query-to-find-parent-with-most-children-excluding-root).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks, I haven't thought about it that way.

Comment: Thank you for your response and I am sorry for the ambiguity. I re-asked the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601829/postgresql-ltree-query-to-find-parent-with-most-children-excluding-root