# Postgresql ltree query to find parent with most children; excluding root

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree, ltree

I am using PostgreSQL and have a table with a path column that is of type `ltree`.

The problem I am trying to solve is: given the whole tree structure,
what parent has the most children excluding the root.

Sample data looks like this:

```
path column = ; has a depth of 0 and has 11 children its id is 1824 # dont want this one because its the root
path column = ; has a depth of 0 and has 1 children its id is 1823
path column = 1823; has a depth of 1 and has 1 children its id is 1825
path column = 1823.1825; has a depth of 2 and has 1 children its id is 1826
path column = 1823.1825.1826; has a depth of 3 and has 1 children its id is 1827
path column = 1823.1825.1826.1827; has a depth of 4 and has 1 children its id is 1828
path column = 1824.1925.1955.1959.1972.1991; has a depth of 6 and has 5 children its id is 2001
path column = 1824.1925.1955.1959.1972.1991.2001; has a depth of 7 and has 1 children its id is 2141
path column = 1824.1925.1955.1959.1972.1991.2001; has a depth of 7 and has 0 children its id is 2040
path column = 1824.1925.1955.1959.1972.1991.2001; has a depth of 7 and has 1 children its id is 2054
path column = 1824.1925.1955.1959.1972.1991.2001; has a depth of 7 and has 0 children its id is 2253
path column = 1824.1925.1955.1959.1972.1991.2001; has a depth of 7 and has 1 children its id is 2166
path column = 1824.1925.1955.1959.1972.1991.2001.2054; has a depth of 8 and has 0 children its id is 2205
path column = 1824.1925.1955.1959.1972.1991.2001.2141; has a depth of 8 and has 0 children its id is 2161
path column = 1824.1925.1955.1959.1972.1991.2001.2166; has a depth of 8 and has 1 children its id is 2389
path column = 1824.1925.1955.1959.1972.1991.2001.2166.2389; has a depth of 9 and has 0 children its id is 2402
path column = 1824.1925.1983; has a depth of 3 and has 1 children its id is 2135
path column = 1824.1925.1983.2135; has a depth of 4 and has 0 children its id is 2239
path column = 1824.1926; has a depth of 2 and has 5 children its id is 1942
path column = 1824.1926; has a depth of 2 and has 11 children its id is 1928 # this is the row I am after
path column = 1824.1926; has a depth of 2 and has 2 children its id is 1933
path column = 1824.1926; has a depth of 2 and has 2 children its id is 1989
path column = 1824.1926.1928; has a depth of 3 and has 3 children its id is 2051
path column = 1824.1926.1928; has a depth of 3 and has 0 children its id is 2024
path column = 1824.1926.1928; has a depth of 3 and has 2 children its id is 1988
```

So, in this example, the row with id **1824** (the root) has 11 children and the row with id **1928** has 11 children with a depth of 2; this is the row I am after.

I am new to ltree and sql for that matter.

(This is a revised question with added sample data after [Ltree find parent with most children postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594565/ltree-find-parent-with-most-children-postgresql) was closed).

Comment: Your test data don't add up. You should provide a working test case (in a form ready to use!) and the query you have tried, even if it's not working.

Comment: "ready to use" means `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` or `COPY` statements. Something we can actually put into PostgreSQL without wasting time reformatting it. Additionally, please *always* show your exact PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Will do this next time. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Solution

To find the node with the most children:

```
SELECT subpath(path, -1, 1), count(*) AS children
FROM   tbl
WHERE  path <> ''
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

... and exclude root nodes:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT ltree2text(subpath(path, -1, 1))::int AS tbl_id, count(*) AS children
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  path <> ''
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) ct
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT tbl_id
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  path = ''
   ) x USING  (tbl_id)
WHERE  x.tbl_id IS NULL
ORDER  BY children DESC
LIMIT  1
```

Assuming that root nodes have an empty `ltree` (`''`) as path. Might be `NULL`. Then use `path IS NULL` ...

The winner in your example is actually `2001`, with 5 children.

[**-> SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/416de/1)

#### How?

- Use the function [**`subpath(...)`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ltree.html#LTREE-FUNC-TABLE) provided by the [the additional module `ltree`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ltree.html).
- Get the *last node* in the path with a **negative offset**, which is the direct parent of the element.
- Count how often that parent appears, exclude root nodes and take the remaining one with the highest count.
- Use [`ltree2text()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ltree.html#LTREE-FUNC-TABLE) to extract the value from `ltree`.
- If multiple nodes have equally the most children an arbitrary one is picked in the example.

#### Test case

This is the work I had to do to get to a useful test case (after trimming some noise):

See [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/416de/1).

In other words: please remember to provide a useful test case next time.

#### Additional columns

Answer to comment.
First, expand the test case:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN postal_code text
              , ADD COLUMN whatever serial;
UPDATE tbl SET postal_code = (1230 + whatever)::text;
```

Have a look:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl;
```

Simply `JOIN` result to the parent in the base table:

```
SELECT ct.*, t.postal_code
FROM  (
   SELECT ltree2text(subpath(path, -1, 1))::int AS tbl_id, count(*) AS children
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  path <> ''
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) ct
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT tbl_id
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  path = ''
   ) x USING  (tbl_id)
JOIN  tbl t USING (tbl_id)
WHERE  x.tbl_id IS NULL
ORDER  BY children DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Comment: Awesome Thank you so much! Works like a charm. Any idea how to includes a belongs_to postal_code so one is able to get result.postal_code.

Comment: Much appreciated! I have next to no experience with SQL. This is helpful to have working examples to play with.